# How to give feedback on a technical test

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, united-kingdom, technology, feedback

I work as part of a small web development team and we are hiring for a new frontend developer.

I was asked to make a technical test for candidates to do pre-interview. The test was a simple landing page. We have now had a few candidates complete this test and have called them in for interviews.

I want to give them feedback on the test. Is it appropriate to give this feedback in the interview or afterwards with the rest of the interview feedback?

This is my first time being an interviewer, I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere We don't have a HR department nor any formalised interview process. We also haven't had as many applicants as we originally planned for and are interviewing the few that have bothered to attempt our test.

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice (I assume that they passed the test and invited to 2nd interview). You can give feedback by your own initiative. Or wait for candidate questions to check if he is curious enough about what could be done better. Tests can be used to ask why candidate chosen particular technology stack or other solution. Also you may ask to implement some simple feature during an interview.